# Auto-update submodule

Tags: git, makefile, git-submodules

I'd like to automatically update a git submodule as part of our build system whenever it is out of sync, i.e. if the checked-out version is not the same as the version recorded in the tree.

Currently I do `git submodule status ‹path›` and check whether the first character of the resulting output is a space (in sync) or something else (`-` for not initialized, `+` for out-of-sync commit, or `U` for merge conflicts).

Is there some cheaper (in terms of execution time) command to obtain this information? Can I perhaps compare timestamps of two suitably chosen files to determine whether the submodule is in need of an update?

Comment: check the option '--cached' helps.

Comment: @Gregg are you sure? In gut parlance, “cache” tends to refer to the staging area. So I read the `--cached` flag as “don't compare actual status with HEAD but with staged changes instead”, which may even be more expensive since it will have to check the staging area (usually without a hit) before falling back to comparing HEAD.

Comment: When the file is in the index, the hash in known so git only has to check it (just the hash) with the latest.  I am not sure so this is just a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The `git submodule` command is implemented as a shell script, although it does request some help from `git submodule--helper`. The [relevant line](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cf4c2cfe52be5bd973a4838f73a35d3959ce2f43/git-submodule.sh#L1018) for the issue at hand is this:

```
git diff-files --ignore-submodules=dirty --quiet -- "$sm_path"
```

This distinguishes a matching commit (space in `git submodule status`) from a differing one (`+` in status). There are other pieces of code which come before and serve to [detect `U` conflicts](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cf4c2cfe52be5bd973a4838f73a35d3959ce2f43/git-submodule.sh#L1004-L1006) (with the [help of `git submodule--helper`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cf4c2cfe52be5bd973a4838f73a35d3959ce2f43/git-submodule.sh#L994-L998)) or [`-` uninitialized submodules](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cf4c2cfe52be5bd973a4838f73a35d3959ce2f43/git-submodule.sh#L1009-L1015).

In my experiments, the case of conflicts (i.e. a merge in the parent repo had conflicting inputs on what commit to use for the submodule) led to a non-zero exit status for the `diff-files` command as well. An uninitialized repository was not reported, though. So I'd suggest the following commands to check whether a submodule is up to date:

```
test -f "$sm_path/.git" -o -d "$sm_path/.git" && \
git diff-files --ignore-submodules=dirty --quiet -- "$sm_path"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this answers your question(s), but it might serve to obtain your ultimate goal:

```
git submodule update --checkout [<submodule>]
```

This will checkout the submodule version which is stored in the tree, unless the already checked-out submodule has modifications which conflict, in which case it will abort.

You could add this as a `post-checkout` hook to do it automatically.

And if you like living dangerously, you could use the following to reset the submodule(s) prior to checkout, so as to avoid conflicts when checking-out the new version.

```
git submodule foreach git reset --hard HEAD
git submodule foreach git clean -f
```

Of course, that will wipe any changes you have in your submodules, so use with caution.